# AsyncSocket just read once?

Tags: iphone, sockets, asyncsocket

I make simple client server with no CLRFdata, but i give header of message with lenght message self. this is my code :

This method send data

```
- (void)sendMessage:(NSString *)message {
unsigned char lendata = [message length];
 senddata = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes: &lendata length:sizeof(lendata)]  ;
[senddata appendData:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[socket writeData:senddata withTimeout:-1 tag:0];  
}
```

This method read data from socket lenght = 1 byte until long of code on header.

```
- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag {
NSString *message = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

if(bheader){
    cdata++;
    if(cdata==2){
        [data getBytes:&idata];
        bheader = NO;
        cdata=0;
        cmessage = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@""];
    }

}
else{  
    if (message){            
        cmessage = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@%@",cmessage,message]  ;
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Error converting received data into UTF-8 String");

    cdata++;
    if(cdata==idata) {
        msgComplete=YES;
    }

}

if (msgComplete) {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:cmessage forKey:kNotificationMessage];
    [notificationCenter postNotificationName:kNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    cmessage=@"";
    msgComplete=NO;
    bheader=YES;
    cdata=0;
    [cmessage release];    
}         
[sock readDataToLength:1 withTimeout:-1 tag:0];  
}
```

and this method

```
- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didWriteDataWithTag:(long)tag {
[sock readDataToLength:1 withTimeout:-1 tag:0];  
}
```

I'm succes send data and recv data from server use this code,
i try make login and server got data and notification, and i recv message with this code, but after that i cant recv message from server when i send message again, but on TCPDUMP i see any message sent to server and server response with a message ?

could any one fix my code where the problem ?
Thanks.

Comment: I has fix this code :D, thanks all.